# Passing Data with a button

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an app(my first) that has several view controllers.

VC1 - is an tableView with a name & image. (a list)

VC2 - is a View with name, image and two buttons. (list add/edit view)
Data passing between these two views works fine using protocols

VC3 - is a tableView with another list. (items for first list)
I have a Button on VC2 that segues to VC3.

So a user enters the first TableView and taps on a tableViewCell, it segues to the second View for editing that selected list. While in the second View(not a tableView) the user taps a button which segues to the third TableView to add/edit the items. Then the user taps the done button sending the user back to the second View.

This is my issue - how do I pickup/associate the list name from VC2 to VC3. When the user taps doneButton the items should be associated with that one list that the user was editing.

thank you, newbie

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson9.html) is a good tutorial from apple showing you how to do just that. The basic idea is that to add things to a table view. Have an array of objects in the VC1 that contains everything you want to show. Then pass that array to VC2 (which in turn passes it to VC3) using `prepareForSegue`. [Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=18471) is a good segue tutorial.

For editing (moving and deleting cells), this had native support so you won't have to roll your own. The bottom of that tutorial link shows how to enable this.

The basic idea for deletion is that you want to remove the element from the array and then redraw the table view (VC1) without that element. Failing to keep the table view and array in sync will result in a crash.

Comment: Yes, that is good tutorial and I have used it for most of my App. But the tutorial 'segue' is using the storyboard. I'm using a button. The tutorial is also using an accessory button on VC1 to go to VC3. The difference is I'm trying to segue from VC2 to VC3 using a button.

Comment: You can achieve this programmatically by initializing your button with a selector method and, within that election method, call 'preformSegue:' to the VC3 controller. This will also in turn call 'prepareForSegue:'

Comment: sorry, i'm fairly new at this. I think you are saying;  

@IBAction func itemsButton() {
  
let navigationController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ItemsViewController") as! UINavigationController

let controller = navigationController.topViewController as! ItemsViewController
  
controller.delegate = self
  
presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil) 
 }

if this is what you are saying, it gives an error of "cannot assign value of type VC1 to type VC2"